# Laravel Method error: Relationship method must return an object of type Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\Relation

Tags: php, laravel-5

I have a method in an class called `Partner` that executes this:

```
$commissionAmount = $subscriptionRevenue * $this->connectStatus()->first()->margin;
```

The `connectStatus` (aslo in `Partner` class) method is:

```
public function connectStatus($date = false)
{
    $lastSnapshot = $this->lastSnapshot($date);

    if ($lastSnapshot) {
        $subscribed = $lastSnapshot->cum_subscribed;
    } else {
        $subscribed = 0;
    }

    return $this->contract()
        ->whereRaw("{$subscribed} BETWEEN connections_from AND connections_to");
}
```

The `contract` method (also in `Partner` class) is

```
public function contract()
{
    return $this->hasMany(PartnerConnectContract::class, 'partner_id');
}
```

My code is failing in `connectStatus` method at:

```
return $this->contract()
    ->whereRaw("{$subscribed} BETWEEN connections_from AND connections_to");
```

With error:

```
Relationship method must return an object of type Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\Relation
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

My problem was using `BETWEEN` for an `integer` comparison. This solved it.

```
public function connectStatus($date = false)
{
    $lastSnapshot = $this->lastSnapshot($date);

    if ($lastSnapshot) {
        $subscribed = $lastSnapshot->cum_subscribed;
    } else {
        $subscribed = 0;
    }

    return $this->contract()
        ->where('connections_from', '<=', $subscribed)
        ->where('connections_to', '>=' , $subscribed)
        ->first();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

We know the method `connectStatus()` definitely doesn't return a `Relation` object.

How about this:

```
// Changed the method name
public function getConnectStatusAttribute()
{
     // ... your code
}
```

And to call it:

`$commissionAmount = $subscriptionRevenue * $this->connect_status->first()->margin;`

Comment: hi @spacemudd, thanks for the help. How do I pass  `$date` to the attribute getter in the call?

Comment: @TheRealPapa I completely spaced out on that one. Yeah, passing $date is not possible on a getter. I worked on something similar like yours though, I'll try to look how it was done. Sorry!

Comment: Hi @Spacemudd, I got it! I was the `BETWEEN` piece in my query!

Comment: @TheRealPapa Oh, that makes sense. Your fix is neat. Cool stuff.